# Login remember me from Ionic

Tags: laravel

I'm making an ionic app with a Laravel backend, I'm creating a login for the App which will authenticate through Laravel API endpoint, my login function is this:

```
 $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Access Token');
 $token = $tokenResult->token;
```

My question is, how could I add a remember me functionality to this? That is, extend the token duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a remember me boolean to your validation

```
'remember_me' => 'boolean'
```

Then make a check if `remember_me` is present, and if so set the token `expirys_at` to however long you want the token to last for, for example 1 week

```
if ($request->remember_me)
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
```

Don't forget to `$token->save();` as it looks like you don't have that in your code